Google slides api quickstart example keep showing This site can’t be reached
I'm a beginner on python and I'm using google colab to follow the instruction on google slides api quickstart. As title mentioned, I tried several ways to run the quickstart sample, but after hit allow button on page " wants to access your Google Account", the page turns to "This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect."
I read several answers on similar problems, but their situation looks a bit different.
